# How to catch http response made by third party application

Tags: javascript, flash, http, web

We have flash player on web site which sends requests to some remote service and receives xml data. We need to catch these responses and analyze what was received by flash player. This job should be performed automatically by some script or tool, so F12 developer tool is not a solution :)

Comment: *"This job should be performed automatically by some script or tool, so F12 developer tool is not a solution"* So what does that actually imply?

Comment: Basically it is not going to happen in the webpage, you are going to have to build a browser extension.

Comment: @epascarello it is imply exactly what I wrote above. automatically means without manual job, what is not clear for you mate?

Answer (score 0):

We decided to use chrome extensions for these purposes. Thanks for advices